# Корки, каблуки чи підбори?

Tags: вибір-слова, значення-слів

*Підбори* та *каблуки*. СУМ подає ці два слова, як синоніми. Хоча, якщо почитати саме визначення, то [*підбори*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidbor) — це набійки на підошві взуття, що не є зовсім тотожним до слова *каблук*. Також зіткнулась із це одним терміном — [*корок*](http://sum.in.ua/s/korok), який СУМ також подає, як синонім до каблука. Але ж корок — це матеріал з якого може бути зроблена підошва взуття. І далеко не кожен каблук є корком за структурою. Чи доцільно до кожного виду каблука вживати слово *"корок"*? І чи тотожні слова *корки, каблуки* та *підбори*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/k/kilka/33-1-0-7602) теж знайшла інформацію, що це синоніми:

> Синоніми до слова КАБЛУК : підбір, обцас, (високий) шпилька.

Отже, "каблук" = "підбір". Про "корок" статті нема.

[Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BA) містить таку статтю:

> **Каблук**, ка, м.
>
> 1) Дуга, часть окружности.
>
> 2) Снарядъ для спугиванія рыбы, состоящій изъ дуги, концы которой соединены доской, оканчивающейся зубьями въ видѣ гребня; бороздя дно, эти зубцы спугиваютъ мелкую рыбу, попадающую въ поставленную раньше сѣть. Дуга наз. каблук, доска съ зубьями — гребінь. Шух. 1. 228.
>
> 3) Лука въ сѣдлѣ. См. Облук. Шух. І. 252.

Тобто тут лексема "каблук" у значення "підбори не подається".

Натомість там же читає іншу статтю:

> **Корок**, рка, м. **Каблукъ**. Чуб. VII. 431. Один чобіт на підкові, а другий на корку. Н. п. Чоботи на височенних корках пошиє, щоб не швидко зносились. Г. Барв. 516. Ум. Корочок. Черевички на корочках височеньких. МВ. ІІ. 77.

Отже, за Грінченком, "корок" = "каблук". Статті ж про "підбори" нема.

Якщо ж знову звернутися до сучасного [СУМ-8](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44247&page=1400) читаємо:

> **Корок** 3. заст. **Підбор** (перев. обтягнутий шкірою); каблук.
>
> Сотничиха дивиться, усміхається, встає, стукає корками і теж пускається у танець (О. Стороженко).

Отже, лексема "корок" вважається застарілою, а "підбор" та "каблуки" - це синоніми.